# Emoji Characters not rendering in iOS Push Notifications

Tags: php, ios, mysql, apple-push-notifications, emoji

A big part of the app I am working on is chat with Push Notifications. The whole system is working great except that when a user sends a message with an emoji in it, the receiver of this message will see this in their push note:

[image: Push Note ScreenShot]

When the receiver taps on the push notification, the emoji's from the message are rendered fine in the app, like so:

[image: In App screenshot]

The messages are stored on my server in a MySQL db, and a php script packages up the push note JSON and sends it to APNS.

Here is the part of my PHP script that packages up the JSON to send to APNS (borrowed mostly from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial):

```
function makePayload($senderName, $text)
    {

            $nameJson = $this->jsonEncode($senderName);
            $nameJson = truncateUtf8($nameJson, 20);

            // Convert and truncate the message text
            $textJson = $this->jsonEncode($text);
            $textJson = truncateUtf8($textJson, self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

            $payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $nameJson . ': ' . $textJson . '","sound":"default"} . '}';
            return $payload;
    }
```

I'm pretty stumped. I'm not sure why iOS isn't parsing the "alert:" portion of my push note JSON correctly. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about PHP, and am not an expert on character sets and encodings, but I would look at if utf8 is the correct thing to apply to an emojis.

Comment: I think it could be a problem with the truncateUtf8 method. Have you attempted to hardcode the textJson string with emoji unicode characters. Do they appear correctly?